# Getting an error stating "Run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable 'rejected' was corrupted. (Visual Studio)

Tags: c

All of my code works great until I press the key to exit my program, which happens when I press'-'. I then get that error and I am not sure how to resolve it. Here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

char rejected[2] = { 0 };
char input = 0;
char exitProgram = 0;

printf("Please enter three letters you want filtered\n");
for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++) {
     scanf("%s", &rejected[x]);
}
printf("Please enter a letter and I will tell you if it is filtered or not\n");
for (int y = 0; y <= 99; y++) {
    scanf("%s", &input);
    if (input == rejected[0] || input == rejected[1] || input == rejected[2]) {
        printf("Filtered letter!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Okay letter!\n");
    }
    if (y %5 == 0) {
        printf("If you would like to exit this program, please enter '-'. If not, please enter '+'\n");
        scanf("%s", &exitProgram);
        if (exitProgram == '+') {
            printf("Okay, continue having fun with my program!\n");
        }
        else if (exitProgram == '-') {
            printf("Thank you for playing with my program!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `rejected` is declared as an array of 2 elements, and you read 3 into it, causing UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `scanf` in three places with the `%s` format specifier, which is used to read a string, and in each of those places it is the incorrect one.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which can cause a crash.

First:

```
scanf("%s", &rejected[x]);
```

Here you're really want to read a single character, so you need the `%c` format specifier.  This one accepts *any* character, including spaces and newlines, so you'll want to precede it with a space to consume any leftover newlines from the prior read:

```
scanf(" %c", &rejected[x]);
```

Second:

```
scanf("%s", &input);
```

`input` is an `char`, so you again want `%c` here:

```
scanf(" %c", &input);
```

Third:

```
scanf("%s", &exitProgram);
```

You're reading a character here, so use `%c` with a leading space as before:

```
scanf(" %c", &exitProgram);
```

You also have a problem here:

```
char rejected[2] = { 0 };
...
for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++) {
     scanf("%s", &rejected[x]);
}
```

The array `rejected` only contains 2 elements but you try to read in 3.  This also invokes undefined behavior by writing past the end of the array.  Change the size of the array to 3.

```
char rejected[3] = { 0 };
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the error has stopped. However, I noticed you said that input should be %d rather than %c, which I do not understand. For input, I am entering in a character to be read (like 'c' or 'p'). Isn't %d just for digits?